# How to list multiple model records ordered by date in one list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm working on ordering system, where a client can request different orders (transfer, shipping, contract, etc.) each of these orders are in different models. I want to implement a page for all client requests, this list should be a combination from **Transfer**, **Shipping**, **Contract** models, and I want to order them by date.

Since I have records from different models, then I believe using Django **ListView** is not an option in this case since ListView requires specifying one model and in my scenario I need three models or even more. I would like to know what is the best way of achieving this in a very effective way?.

**NOTE:** I don't want to combine all of these models into one models, as all of them have different requirements and procedures.

I'm thinking of creating a **TemplateView** and call a function in the get_context_data() which calls all the models, chain the, then order them using lambda function. BUT, I think this approach is not recommended when I have a filtration fields (client ID, Request Date, Request Type, Request Status, etc.) in the same page to filter the list, where having these form fields would require calling the function each time and changing query based on that. So, is this the best solution or do you have a better one?

These are Examples of how my models look like, as they don't have direct relationship with each other:

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="transfer_orders")
    requested_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ......


class Shipping(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shipping_orders")
    requested_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ......

    
class Contract(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contract_orders")
    requested_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ......
```

My function currently looks similar to this:

```
def get_orders_list():
    transfer = Transfer.objects.all()
    shipping = Shipping.objects.all()
    contract = Contract.objects.all()
    orders_list = sorted(chain(transfer, shipping, contract), key=lambda instance: instance.requested_date, reverse=True)
    return orders_list
```